# Где находится PHPUnit_Framework_MockObject_MockObject класс?

Tags: php, symfony2, phpunit, symfony3

Phpstorm не видит файла, начинаю искать не нахожу, если у кого то можно просмотреть этот класс напишите где он лежит, все что не мокаешь подсвечивает, уже бесить начинает =)

Comment: Подчерки, которые вы видете - это заменители слешей в устаревшей конвенции, поэтому вам достаточно найти папку с сорцами PHPUnit и пройтись по пути Framework/MockObject/MockObject.php

Comment: @Etki нет такого https://sc-cdn.scaleengine.net/i/a0c0e62d4a483a55547e88e0d2157d11.png

Comment: Вероятно, он лежит отдельным пакетом

Comment: @Etki да магия какая то думал может тут кто подскажет где искать =) не охото ковырять все файлы phpunit

Comment: да гвоорю же, соседний пакет https://packagist.org/packages/phpunit/phpunit-mock-objects https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit-mock-objects/blob/master/src/Framework/MockObject/MockObject.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем в Phpstorm нужно указать путь именно на исполняемый phpunit.phar

> Внимание!
>   Шторм файл не увидит, придется прописать руками, потом он расширение
>   может удалить, снова берем и прописываем руками.

```
chmod +x phpunit.phar
```

Answer (score 0):

Добавьте архив `PHPUnit.phar` в external library path. в самом низу дерева проэкта. И он подгрузит файлы с архива.

Из комментариев для подсветкитаких переменных надо использовать dockblock php.

для примера

```
$doctrine = $this->addDoctrineService();
$doctrine->expects()..etc...
```

для начало определяем тот класс который имеет переменная с помощью `get_class`

```
var_dump(get_class($doctrine));
```

допустим вывод `PHPUnit_Framework_MockObject_MockObject` то пишем

```
/** @var PHPUnit_Framework_MockObject_MockObject $doctrine **/
$doctrine = $this->addDoctrineService();
```

так же над методами стоит писать док блоки, к примеру

```
/**
 * @return Class_Name_For_Use
 */
 public function returnClassName()
 { 
    return $object;
 }
```

Почитайте про php-doc чем больше документирован код тем больше phpstorm будет подсказывать.

Comment: подключен сурс но там нет этого файла соответственно подчеркивает https://sc-cdn.scaleengine.net/i/1bf10c38a9c19e3c10dd70073a9dc51f5.png

Comment: @SergeEsmanovich этоже класс а не namespace

Comment: так вот этого класса нет

Comment: так зачем вы пишите `use`? напиште как вы используете его в коде

Comment: Какая разница, он и в use  должен быть доступен и в аннотациях, дело в том что тесты работают мне приходится по памяти писать  методы    этого класса. Если есть этот класс залей его на гугл док и кинь ссылку да и делов то

Comment: @SergeEsmanovich код приведи как ты его используешь в коде? как инстацируешь?

Comment: Вот так https://sc-cdn.scaleengine.net/i/bef52c19c9d50736c46f993b6e7aa5de.png

Comment: Или так =) https://sc-cdn.scaleengine.net/i/5d3d53065316f63234950bd9136e6289.png

Comment: @SergeEsmanovich попрой doc-bock прописать смотри в ответе поправил.